# Python Absolute Path - wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Whilst running a novice project in Python, I tried to find the absolute path of a file given its relative file path, but I end up with the wrong absolute file path. One of the folders is not shown in the output.

Here is the code:

```
import os
a = os.path.abspath("abc.txt")
print(a)
```

This is what I get as an output:
/Users/***/abc.txt

But when I check the file directory of my abc.txt file, the actual file path is: /Users/***/Documents/abc.txt.

Hence when I use this output in another file I end up with errors that this file isn't found. Can anyone tell me the logic behind this and what I should do to display the full file path?

Comment: don't mix up python script directory and current execution directory. Where is `abc.txt` located? where the python script is?

Comment: It is in the same directory of abc.txt. Does abspath give current execution directory?

Comment: Thank you so much! @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Comment: you're welcome. Please accept the duplicate so the question can be closed.